# jQuery - removeClass not work when element have multiple class

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, input, click

Hi I have problem with `removeClass()` function.
What I need is every check/uncheck action on specified checkbox element should in `select` field below, add or remove class defined by the value of clicked checkbox. Unfortunately this works fine only when you make click action alternately at both checkboxes. When `option` element have multiple classes and you click same checkbox which you have previously clicked, classes do not want to be removed.

Thank You for every explanation of this issue and help to fix it.

**HTML**

```
<span>
  <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="1" > <label for="bahn_1">CB 1</label>
</span>
<span>
  <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="2" > <label for="bahn_2">CB 2</label>
</span>

<select class="select" name="start_1" required>
  <option value="" selected disabled>Choose option</option>
  <option value="15:00">15:00</option>
  <option value="16:00">16:00</option>
  <option value="17:00">17:00</option>
</select>
```

**jQuery**

```
<script>
$('.checkbox').click(function() {

  var thisVal = $(this).val();
  checked = $(this).is(":checked");

  if(checked) {

        $('select').find('option[value="16:00"]').addClass('class' + thisVal);

  } else {

    $("select").find("option[class^='class" + thisVal + "']").each(function(){

        $("select option[class^='class" + thisVal + "']").removeClass("class" + thisVal);

    });

  }
});
</script>
```

**jsFiddle**

https://jsfiddle.net/X9DESIGN/ahprcn03/16/

====

I definitely used wrong combination of functions and selectors content. My fault.

**Solution with example:**

`$("select").find("option[class^='class" + thisVal + "']")`

is wrong, but

`$("select option.class" + thisVal)`

is perfect.

Comment: With `checkbox` use `.on('change' , function(){` instead of `.click(function(){` .. Your code works fine for me it add/remove classes .. please try to explain well what are you trying to do

Comment: Also no need to use `.each()` it'll be enough to use `$("select option.class" + thisVal).....`

Comment: Hello, thank you for your response. Try to make both checkboxes checked and then click (make unchecked) same chockbox which you clicked previously. `option` field in which a class defined by clicked checkbox should be removed, do not want to be remove.

Changing to `change()` function not help.

Comment: `.change` just to let you know the better way to deal with `checkbox/radio` inputs .. what your code do is to `add/remove` `class1,class2` to the `option` which has value of `16:00` and that is exactly what your code doing https://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/vdc4wsma/3/ its already `add/remove` the classes correctly from the `option[value="16:00"]`

Comment: I definitely used wrong combination of functions and selectors content. My fault. Example: `$("select").find("option[class^='class" + thisVal + "']")` is wrong, but `$("select option.class" + thisVal)` is perfect.  Your code works fine. Thank You.

Comment: Never mind @X9DESIGN .. Have a nice day :-)